Error “Could not materialize Objective-C class named ‘Array’ from declared attribute value type ‘Array’”
I’m trying to save data to a SwiftData database, but I keep running into this error:
Could not materialize Objective-C class named "Array" from declared attribute value type "Array<Int>" of attribute named qualification.

The error occurs when attempting to save an instance of UserModel to the database. Below is the code for my model and save function:
@Model
class UserModel: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var email: String
    var avatar: Data?
    var rank: Int
    var qualification: [Int] = []
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)  var credentials: [Credential] = []

    init(id: UUID, name: String, surname: String, email: String, avatar: Data? = nil, rank: Int, qualification: [Int], credentials: [Credential]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email
        self.avatar = avatar
        self.rank = rank
        self.qualification = qualification
        self.credentials = credentials
    }
}

@Model
class Credential: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var email: String
    var password: String
    var user: UserModel?

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), email: String, password: String, user: UserModel? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.user = user
    }
}


The error seems to be related to the qualification property, which is an array of integers ([Int]). Here’s how I’m creating and saving a UserModel instance:
How can I fix this error? Do I need to change the type of qualification, or is there a workaround for saving an array of integers in SwiftData?
